# SQL Query concatenation flagged in SonarQube

Tags: sql, sonarqube

I have a method where I get a sql query as parameter. This is used in an IN clause to form a bigger query to Select/Delete data. Something like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'HR'"
BIG_SQL = "DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID IN ("+SQL+")
```

It was flagged by `SonarQube`. Is there a better way to write the above code?

Comment: what about `DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'HR'`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the purpose of the 2 queries is to delete rows from the table.
In the table `EMPLOYEE` the column `ID` is the primary key, right?
So you could just have a `DELETE` statement like this:

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'HR'
```

There is no need to get the ids by using the condition:

```
WHERE DEPARTMENT = 'HR'
```

and then use them to delete since this condition can be applied to directly delete the rows.

Comment: I probably should have added it in the question. The example I came up with was a simple one. The system is more complex. Just need help understanding whether this can actually cause any harm such as SQL injection or can I just suppress the rule in this case if the smaller query is also created by the system and is not a direct user input.

Comment: Concatenation of sql statements are always risky and must be avoided, even when they are created by the *system*. This is why every programming language provides the means to handle such cases by passing parameters to placeholders in the form of arguments in prepared statements or similar objects.